# Stripe Coupon/Discount with a One Time Payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Does anyone know if it's possible to accept coupons on a one time transaction with Stripe?

I know you can add coupons with recurring subscriptions but I just want to be able to offer a discount on one time payments.

Answer (score 12):

I think the idea here is that you are in total control of individual charges (or one-time payments, whatever you want to call them). So, you can create whatever coupon mechanism in your own app for charges. At the end of the day you're just telling Stripe "Charge $X.YZ to this card".

It's a little different for subscriptions because they are more structured data. They rely on a plan, which has a set price.

Hopefully that makes sense, but I agree that it's weird that they don't let you apply a coupon to a single charge.

Answer (score 6):

No, not possible.  Their documentation states it's only for invoices with subscriptions or invoice items.

https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#coupons

Answer (score 1):

Applying discount coupons for `one-time charges` is unnecessary burden for `Stripe` to maintain. So they do not support this and recommend us to keep the record of `discount coupons` for one time charges our selves.

Also it does not make much sense. So here is how to do this

- You have `discount coupons` already set in the `Stripe`
- When your customer submits `coupon` for one-time charges, you get the `amount` or `%age` to wave off
- and reduce the amount from the price and call `Stripe API` to charge the discounted amount.
- You will need to keep track of `discounted amount` and `coupon` for such charges your self.

Illustration:
**Pseudo code**

```
coupon = params[:promo_code]
discounted_amount = coupon.discount_amount
amount_to_charge = actual_price - discounted_amount
Stripe::Charge.create(customer: cust_id, amount_to_charge)

# update the coupon and charge info in local database
```

For more info see this link

https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/coupons-for-charges